# Hide create Button and upload button in alfresco Doclib

Tags: alfresco-share

I want to show Create and upload button inside Document Library only, and in document library if I will create any sub folder. Then inside that sub folder I don't want to allow any user to create any folder or upload any document.

Is is possible to do this in alfresco 5.0.d

Please refer below image.
In that image I want to hide that create and upload option. But I want to show both option for specific folder only (i.e Document Library)

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth remembering that if you just hide the "Create Content" and "Upload" buttons that it won't prevent users from creating content by dragging and dropping files into the Document Library to trigger an upload - nor will it stop the creation of content via other mechanisms such as the mobile client or other APIs like WebDav (if your organisation happens to be using them).

The most effective method to prevent upload and content creation would be to ensure that all folders created at the root of the Document Library do not allow children to be created within them.

If the "CreateChildren" permission on the folders is false then the Upload and Create actions will automatically be disabled without you having to do anything - and this will also prevent drag-and-drop file upload from being possible.

I would suggest that you look at the best approach to take. Again, there are various ways in which this can be achieved - setting folder rules would be one approach (to change the permission on all folders created), overriding the REST APIs would be another option.

However, if you're looking for a less than ideal short cut to just hiding the buttons then you're going to need to extend the toolbar.js code that is used in the Document Library.

This [blog post](https://www.alfresco.com/blogs/developer/2012/05/22/customizing-share-javascript-widget-instantiation-part-1/) provides information on how you can extend existing JavaScript widgets. The WebScript you're going to want to extend in your case is the "documentlist-v2.get.js" (as of 5.0 this creates both the toolbar and documentlist widgets). It is the "onFilterChanged" function that you'll want to extend so that you can hide the buttons when the new path is anything other than the root folder.

Comment: Your answer is really help full for me. it changed my complete way of thinking.  Thank you so much. i will prefer the method which is more effective. please tell me that how exactly can i do this. so my Document Library will do not allow children to be created within them.   Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think setting folder rules would be the best and easy approach.  if possible, please provide the simple js code to set permission. so i will set the rule on document liberary, and execute that script.   Thanks

Comment: Hi Dave,  Actually in my case i am creating one folder in document library and on document library, i have set 1 rule to create some required folders internally through java script. so my requirement is i want to i want to allow user to create folder inside document library only.   in user will create folder inside sub folder then rule is not executing which i set to document library. and also internal directory is not created properly. please suggest the way...........

Comment: i tried your solution, means i created one js to change permission for internal folders. but this time it not allowing my js to create some default folders through code.  So lot of confusion is there. so can you please simplify it, how can i do this exactly.

Comment: Hi, I have tried all the ways, but still i am not able to achieve this. can you please provide the code??   Thanks in advance